# Hive query regexp_extract

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to extract the ip address from "[223.104.227.42]".
I want to extract the 223.104.227.42 between '[' and ']',
Im using this query:

```
select regexp_extract('[223.104.227.42]', '\\[(.*?)\\]')
```

But I get an error:

> FAILED: In function regexp_extract, pattern must has one group reference at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify capturing group index as a parameter (1):

```
hive> select regexp_extract('[223.104.227.42]', '\\[(.*?)\\]',1);
OK
223.104.227.42
Time taken: 0.294 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Thank You @leftjoin but why use double \

Comment: @tangjiyi Because Hive uses Java flavor regex and in Java regex \ has a special meaning and used for predefined characters like \t, \n